# Using Fiddler, how do I get Total Transfer Time as displayed on the Transfer Timeline?

Tags: fiddler

I'm looking at the Transfer Timeline in Fiddler. How do I get the Total transfer time for all sessions? Using the waterfall chart, I can estimate the total transfer time but I'd like a more accurate answer. I see individual transfer times for the sessions but summing them will not produce an accurate result due to concurrent service calls. How do I get the total transfer time from when the client sends the first bit to the client receiving the last bit?

Answer (score 0):

The `Statistics` tab is what you're looking for. Select all of the Sessions of interest and look at the data at the top of that tab.

You want the `Sequence (clock) duration` value.